# Anotate a function argument type

Tags: python, annotations

Having a method like:

```
def pdf_repr(self, users):
    ···
```

I know I could annotate the argument lines with

```
users: list
```

But, if the list is composed by, say:

```
class User:
    ...
```

objects, Could I annotate the argument in some way to describe not only the list but also, the inner objects?

I'd need this, so the editor could help me with auto-complete and not have to check the attributes of the User objects or remember them.

Or, if it is another way to achieve this, I'd like to know. I'm using VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List` from typing library to explicitly type a list of custom class objects.

```py
from typing import List

class User:
    pass

def pdf_repr(self, users: List[User]):
    pass
```

Take a look at the typing library [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics).

Comment: I'll give an upvote because you truly answer my question, but, vs code is still not helping with the autocomplete. It seems like it works sometimes haha. Any idea? Ok, they don't allow me to give an upvote, because I do not have 15 reputation points.

Comment: @user17189165 Then mark the answer as the solution to the question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know, I thought the upvote was meant the solution is correct.